# Navigation Links Not Working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I am working on a website, the site is http://fredsrewards.loyaltylane.com/fredsshopper.  There is a navigation menu at the top of the page.  The links don't work in Chrome or Firefox but they do work in IE9.  The site uses a few javascript files.  I have tried changing things in the CSS and HTML but nothing works.  The site was built using MVC 3.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have another div (phar_panel) on top of the navigation.

You can fix it by setting:

```
#m_box {
    /* rules you already have */
    position: relative;
}

#phar_panel {
    /* rules you already have */
    width: 230px;
    height:31px;
    right:30px;
    position: absolute;
}
#phar_panel img {
    /* rules you already have */
    left: 230px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Also, be careful, you have more than one element with the same id (navigation) in your page!

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Myself and another developer have been banging our heads against the wall for a while now.